# jQuery Animate Upwards

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have an issue where I have a div that is positioned absoutely and I want to animate it off the page upwards (I'm animating a person jumping off the screen).

However, I need the element to be bottom: 0, but when I want the animation to finish I want the image to have top: -600px.

When I write

```
$("#jumper").animate({ 
    top: "-600px"
}, 2000, 'easeInBack' );
```

it sets top top to 0 and then starts the animation.

Perhaps there is a way to get the ypos of the element and set top with jQuery.css() on window load?

What should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just animating the `bottom` property? You could get the height of the document, then add `600` to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kavY4/

```
var height = $(document).height();

$("#jumper").animate({ 
    bottom: height + 600
}, 2000, 'easeInBack' ); ​
```

Otherwise, you run into browser specific issues where the `top` is calculated to be `auto`, and the animation tries to start from that position (which ends up being 0, I guess).

To make that work you would have to get the top position of `#jumper` and set the `top` property to that value manually before you animate.

```
var top = $('#jumper').offset().top;

$("#jumper").css({top:top, bottom:'auto'})
.animate({ 
    top: -600
}, 2000, 'easeInBack' );
```

**EDIT:** The second example required `bottom` to be set to `auto` as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/kavY4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with your code : http://www.jsfiddle.net/fJKah/

looks to work as expected to me. maybe something else is interfering ..

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/fJKah/1/

It doesn't seem to be working for me. By the way I'm using Chrome but it shouldn't matter.